# Cannot trigger dispatches GitHub API by Contenful webhook

Tags: github, github-actions, content-management-system, webhooks, contentful

How can I trigger github action using Contentful webohook?

Now I have webhook configured like this: https://prnt.sc/zMUzVP_rkcn3 / https://prnt.sc/TrMSJkxnOAva

and here is a github action

```
name: Deploy

# Run the workflow when a Contentful webhook is triggered
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [contentful.deploy]

jobs:
  web-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

But nothing happen after change in CMS. When I click at [https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/dispatches](https://api.github.com/repos/%7Bowner%7D/%7Brepo%7D/dispatches)

I get such info

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest"
}
```

Why? Everything is public and I also generate Personal access tokens with workflow, write:packages admin:public_key admin:repo_hook scopes

Comment: Hey, did you check the webhook logs in Contentful? Also, another way to test this out will to be use a tool like Postman and make a POST request. If you click on the `api.github.com...` link, it will return the error you received since the browser will make a GET request instead of a POST request.

Comment: Hi, yes I check everything is 204 code --> https://prnt.sc/rNmm_rq9K9v3

Comment: Then it might be something on the GitHub side. I tried re-creating the whole thing, and it is working for me. I am not sure why it's not working for you.